# what is the best way to access youtube data api with c#

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube.net-api, youtube-data-api

I'm wondering what the best supported way of accessing the youtube data api is with c#?

Are any of the library's up to date? I can quite easily switch to Django or Rails for this app, but thought I would start with C# as it seems that it is referred to in the current docs. However the examples seem inconsistent, so I'd rather just switch to something that works than mess about with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And you can get c# examples at https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet

and the library is in https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/youtube/v3

Comment: your link is broken.

Comment: project is moved, updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a variety of libraries to make this fairly simple:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries

Including this .NET version:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/